# Can not access my model anymore Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with one of my model.

- Model File name : Top.php
- Model Class name : Top
- Table name in db : tops
- Attribute $table value in model : tops

The content of my model.

```
    protected $table = 'tops';
    protected $fillable = array('*');
    protected $guarded = array();
    protected $hidden = array();

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Article', 'articles_has_tops', 'tops_id', 'articles_id')->withPivot('range');
    }
```

Since 10 minutes when I try to access to that model, it redirect me on internal_error.html...
so if I do that `Top::all()` it redirect me whereas all the others models work perfectly...

Any idea ?

**EDIT**

I get my mistake, with the PHP version (5.4) on my dreamhost server, I can not do this dirty test on a if statement:

```
if ( !empty(self::all()->toArray() ) {}
```

So when I try To get my model, it detects this error and redirect me to the www.website.com/internal_error.html/ ... and I still don't understand this part.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post the contents of your model file, `Top.php`, along with the actual code you are using when you call `Top::all()` and receive an error.

Comment: I edit with the content of my model.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you can't use a wildcard in `$fillable`, and you should not use both `fillable` and `guarded`. If you want all your columns to be mass-assignable (though that is generally not a good practice), just specify `$guarded = array()`, or leave both out altogether.

Comment: Please post the code where you are calling `Top::all()`. Also, have you tested by trying to access the model in it's simplest form, i.e., by commenting out the `articles()` relationship, and anything else you might have in the model?

Comment: You have some error in the code, probably in the model itself. Turn on the `debug` and get the exception that is being thrown, then you will know exactly where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  you haven't created another class called Top. It happened to me, when I created a migration, and called it class the same name as the model.